# Auth issue while using IBM MQ using Mulesoft (Mule 4)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq, mulesoft

I am trying to create a poc application to use the IBM Mq connector in mule 4.
I have created a queue manager on IBM Cloud and have the necessary details for connection.

I have also created an application for which I have a username and an API-KEY.

In the MQ config in mulesoft I am passing application username and API-KEY and it gives me `JMSWMQ2013` error which is for auth issue and the username and password are incorrect.

I have used `CLOUD.APP.SVRCONN` and `CLOUD.ADMIN.SVRCONN` but nothing seems to be working.

Just an FYI I am new to IBM cloud and don't have a full understanding of how things work in IBM cloud

Comment: Please check the queue manager logs, they will have details on what caused the `JMSWMQ2013` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual problem with JMS authentication in cloud setups is that the password (apikey) is longer than 12 characters. To force the MQ JMS client to permit longer passwords you need to set a system property. Don't know how you do that with the Mule config but from the command line for Java programs it's `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=Y` (and carefully note the case of that property).